# FB Analytics not sending/tracking events properly?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, google-analytics

Havn't found a word about my problem on the internet so lets find out if anyone has a clue here at stack? My FB tracking code is not working properly. Actualy it doesn't make any sense at all.

In my app I use both Google Analytics tracking and Facebook tracking. Whenever a certain event occur, lets call it event X, I send this via a method to both FB / GA. For example when someone upgrades to Premium version of the app:

```
- (void) appActivated{

....Some Google Analytics code.....

[FBSDKAppEvents logPurchase:49 currency:@"SEK"];
}
```

Google Analytics reports the correct number of events all the time. But Facebook reports only 60-80% of the events. For some reason it does not send / receive all events? I find it hard to belive there is something wrong with my code due to:

**1. Google Analytics code works fine and is being sent from same methods.**

**2. Facebook Analytics is sending data but for some reason not all of it?**

I am using the latest FBSDK in iOS. Same problems goes with my Android app aswell? Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Were you able to identify the cause of this issue? Did this happen only with a particular event or did you see discrepancies between Facebook Analytics and Google Analytics figures for all events?

Comment: I have this same problem (4 years later!) but it's more extreme: Facebook for iOS only reports like 2-3% of the app events that my other analytics system reports.